# Find first occurrence of a string from a vector<string>

Tags: c++, boost, std

I have a `vector<string> vectorStrings` with values: `ta, bc, ac, st, cer, cda`. I want to find the first occurrence of any of the strings in the vector in an input string.

e.g.

```
InputStr = "this certainly helps";
```

Of the given strings in the vector, I would want a way to say `"cer"` was the first occurrence at position `5`.

---

```
int min = 9999999;
string first;

for(int i = 0; i < vectorStrings.size(); i++)
{
    int pos = InputStr.find(vectorStrings[i]);

    if(pos == string::npos)
        continue;

    if(pos < min)
    {
        min = pos;
        first = vectorStrings[i];
    }
}

// values of min and first gives which string occurred first
// and at the position of it in the input string
```

This implementation works, but I would want to know if there exists a more elegant way to do this with boost libraries or std library.

I am working on Windows and using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I don't know about elegant, but I think the outer loop should go over the string characters and the inner loop(in your case - find)  over the strings in your vector. I think that would be more efficient

Comment: You could make min `string::size_type min = string::npos;` (which might also allow you to get rid of the `pos == npos` test).

Comment: You could use an iterator. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a MapReduce problem.

First, you want to go from `vector<string>` to `vector<int>`, of their positions, which is a map, and then you want to reduce the values to one value by their minimum, which is a reduction. First, the map. This is `std::transform`.

```
std::vector<std::string> stuff;
std::string input;
// fill stuff and input
std::vector<int> positions;
std::transform(
    stuff.begin(), 
    stuff.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(positions), 
    [&](std::string& stuff) {
        return input.find(stuff);
    }
);
```

Now we simply use `std::min_element` to get the smallest element, the reduce.

```
auto iterator = std::min_element(positions.begin(), positions.end());
int index = *iterator;
```

To find the string that was found there, it's a simple bit of iterator arithmetic:

```
string found = stuff[iterator - positions.begin()];
```

Comment: Just for the sake of doing it I tried to write a C++03 non-boost equivalent. After I fiddled the member function pointer cast for `find` together I remembered that `mem_fun_ref` only works for unary functions. Just in case OP attempts the same.

Comment: with c++20, is it possible to use find_first_of or not? please update!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know generic boost algorithms for this task.
Your algorithm is correct and should work fine on small dimensions. If you have large vector of strings you might want to use a bit more complicated tree structures for this task. For example, you can organize your vector of strings into tree to speed up the search.
You could you use suffix tree as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Find
{
public:
    std::vector<std::string> vectorStrings;
    std::map<size_t, std::string> positions;

    size_t find(std::string str)
    {
        for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = vectorStrings.begin();
            i != vectorStrings.end();
            ++i)
        {
            positions[str.find(*i)] = *i;
        }

        return (*(positions.begin())).first;
    }
};
```